# Check value from a string after a special character if it's not empty

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

im working in little projet, and i have a little issue

So first im working in a form with differents inputs

> the first input called by **ID** is **#name**

I try to write a code to check if my user fill the input correctly with this tructure

> fisrtname**_**lastname

what i try to do on my sence, is to check first if the user type ( **_** ) in the input, and check if he continue to add more infos after the special character.

and the others steps is when he fill in the right way the submit button is actif

> $('#submit').removeAttr('disabled');

if its not its gona be inactif

> $('#submit').attr('disabled', 'disabled');

- ** input code**

```
<input type="text" class="form-control text" name="p_Nom" id="name" maxlength="24" placeholder="firstname_Prenom" />
```

- ** Jquery part **

```
$('#name').keyup(function() {
    $('#submit').attr('disabled');
    let val = $(this).val();

    if( (val.includes('_')) && (val.substr(val.indexOf('_') + 1) == null) ){
        $('#submit').removeAttr('disabled');
    } else{
        $('#submit').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might consider using a regex instead: use the pattern `[A-Za-z]+_[A-Za-z]+` for the input. No jQuery necessary:

```html
<form>
  <input pattern="[A-Za-z]+_[A-Za-z]+">
  <button>Submit</button>
</form>
```

Or, to permit other non-alphabetical characters, use a negative character set instead:

```html
<form>
  <input pattern="[^_]+_[^_]+">
  <button>Submit</button>
</form>
```

If you also need to run Javascript when invalid, add an `invalid` event listener:

```js
$('input').on('invalid', () => {
  console.log('invalid');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <input pattern="[^_]+_[^_]+">
  <button>Submit</button>
</form>
```